# How to prove stability of sorting algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, correctness-proof

I know to prove instability, we can simply provide a counter-example. But is there a general way to prove that a sorting algorithm is stable? Could you please tell a general method and then show an example perhaps on insertion or merge sort.

Comment: Note that, in general, proof is a creative process and one can't usually give general methods. But it's possible that stability of sorting algorithms is a specific enough domain that there are specific techniques.

Comment: One proof technique which comes to mind is: show that if $A[i] = A[j]$ for some $i < j$, then the elements $A[i],A[j]$ end up in the correct order in the sorted array.

Comment: Making @YuvalFilmus's idea a bit more concrete, if the algorithm consists of a number of phases, it would suffice to show that each phase preserves the order of a pair of equal values.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That's the claim, not a proof technique.

Comment: @j_random_hacker's proposal in formal terms: perform an induction over the steps of the algorithm.

Comment: Is it a comparison-based sorting algorithm?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/51489/755